# Apply timeout control over Camel route

Tags: apache-camel

I'd like to start a route and apply a timer/timeout control setting. If the route doesn't finish before the timeout, an exception could be thrown, and the original route thread (path) must be stopped. I have looked at NotifyBuilder, SEDA, Timer + wiretap, Aggregater, and     Camel BAM. None of them seems having a built-in feature to stop the original route thread. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks

This is the code frame I am thinking about:

```
OnException(Exception.class)  
.handled(true)  
.to(dead_uri).end()// handle timeout exception and quite the current route thread  

from(uri)  
  //start timer or set timeout something  
  .to(process_uri);
```

I know Camel JMS has timeout control, but I don't want to use JMS merely because I need timeout for my route. SEDA has timeout control but SEDA timeout will be in a different thread. How can I stop the original thread for "process_uri"?

Comment: Mostly, when doing a callout from a route, to some syncrhonous protocol you don't have control over, you typically set a time out value there. You may want to provide more info on the route in detail for people to find out a solution for you

Comment: another thing: the SEDA and JMS components has timeout values, that is, you can put a request that waits for a reply for a certain time only, if a timeout occurs, you should be able to throw an execption (hence terminating the partiular exchange (or at least, put it to the error handler).

Comment: Thanks @Petter. I added original contents and will try more on SEDA.

Comment: Since SEDA is in asynchronization scheme and the timeout only notifies the producer, how can the "particular exchange" i.e. the consumer be terminated upon the timeout?

Comment: Did you find a way to have a global timeout, for the whole route?

Answer (score 0):

If you want stop the route if the Route is not finished within specified time the I think using one more timer to check if the Route has finished its processing.(Look at the RoutePolicy) - if that helps you.

and use controbus stop/starting the route.

```
from("timer://checkIfProcessed?repeatCount=1")
    .process(new Processor(){
void process(Exchange exc){
// check the status of the route and send a signal using controlbus , u could use if(status?)
producerTempalte.asyncSend("controlbus:route?routeId="+"theRouteYouWantToStop"+"&action=stop", exchange);
}
}
).end();
```

there is catch here, it wont be stopped if its processing, hence you will have to remove the exchanges from InflightRepository..

Hope this helps.